# Can I replay a Saga in Axon Framework without rerunning old transactions?

Tags: axon

Is there a way to replay a Saga instance in Axon Framework in such a manner that the transactions that already happened are not replayed?

Comment: It would be helpful to be clearer on your use case here, or at all why you need this. Others can share a simple yes or no, but you are asking this with another background then just yes/no I assume. Hence, please provide further details here.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is no @2011ashwini. The Saga's you create in Axon Framework are backed by a dedicated type of Event Handling Component, which enforces that the reset API (provided by the `TrackingEventProcessor`) has zero impact.

It is this exact API which is the only means to *tell* Axon Framework you are doing triggering a replay, thus the only means to use things like Axon's `@ResetHandler`, `@DisallowReplay` and `ReplayStatus` parameter (as described further [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#replaying-events)). Only through these handles would you be able to know whether the Saga is handling events a second time (as you are replaying) yes or no.

The only way to thus forcefully replay a Saga, is by dropping the `TrackingToken` which is stored for it.

**However**, Saga's typically introduce side effects. Especially side effects are things you normally **would not want to be replayed**, ever. Hence why this is closed of by Axon's Saga logic to begin with.

On top of that, you've asked the following:

> Is there a way to replay a Saga instance in Axon Framework in such a manner that *the transactions that already happened are not replayed*?

To be honest with you, that doesn't sound like a replay at all. The transaction which have been performed by the Saga are done so by the events it has handled. Replaying means re-handling those exact same events. Thus you are somewhat contradicting yourself with the question you are asking (hence why I asked for clarification).

Regardless, I hope this provides the additional background you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steven that's answers my question